# Issue piping variables into popen command with Python Azure CLI

Tags: python, html, subprocess

My current issue is I am creating an application with python and HTML to use HTML forms to gather data that is then turned into a variable in Python and then I use the subprocess POPEN to send an Azure CLI command to the azure tenant. When I use the following code for the command it is returning an error.

Python Code

```
def storageaccountcreate():
    name = request.form['storageaccountname']
    resourcegroup = request.form['resourcegroup']
    subscription = request.form['subscriptionid']
    location = request.form['location']
    sku = request.form['sku']
    command = Popen("az storage account create -n name -g resourcegroup --subscription subscriptionid -l location --sku sku", shell=True ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    text = command.stdout.read().decode("ascii") 
    print(text)
    with open("file.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(text)
    return redirect('/')
```

Error

```
Subscription 'subscriptionid' not recognized.
az storage account create: 'sku' is not a valid value for '--sku'. See 'az storage account create --help'.
```

I can clearly tell that it is looking at it as plain text without any variables. How can I add the variables to the command? Here is how the command should look below when being passed to Azure.

```
az storage account create -n NameVariable -g ResourceGroupVariable --subscription SubscriptionIDVariable -l LocationVariable --sku SkuVariable
```

Comment: format the string beforehand?

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm new to Python as well as these operation so I'm not familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Format` your string like this:

```
"az storage account create -n {name} -g {resourcegroup} --subscription {subscriptionid} -l {location} --sku {sku}".format(name=name, resourcegroup=resourcegroup, subscriptionid=subcription, location=location, sku=sku)
```

You can also use f-strings:

```
f"az storage account create -n {name} -g {resourcegroup} --subscription {subscription} -l {location} --sku {sku}"
```

Comment: Are you meaning to change my current string and simply add the {} around the variable names?

Comment: Sorry I really suck at this without examples using my existing code lol I want to be sure I'm putting things in the right places.

Comment: When trying this I received the following error 

File "C:\Users\PP284QZ\Desktop\repo\ms-identity-python-webapp-master\app.py", line 65, in storageaccountcreate
    command = Popen("az storage account create -n {name} -g {resourcegroup} --subscription {subscriptionid} -l {location} --sku {sku}".format(name=name, resourcegroup=resourcegroup, subcriptionid=subscription, location=location, sku=sku), shell=True ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
KeyError: 'subscriptionid'

Comment: I fixed the typo in my answer. Should be `subscriptionid=subcription`

Comment: I am still getting this error 

File "C:\Users\PP284QZ\Desktop\repo\ms-identity-python-webapp-master\app.py", line 65, in storageaccountcreate
    command = Popen("az storage account create -n {name} -g {resourcegroup} --subscription {subscription} -l {location} --sku {sku}".format(name=name, resourcegroup=resourcegroup, subcription=subscription, location=location, sku=sku), shell=True ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
KeyError: 'subscription'

Comment: I changed my code around to try and get it to work but I still keep getting stuck on the subscription for some reason.

Comment: command = Popen("az storage account create -n {name} -g {resourcegroup} --subscription {subscription} -l {location} --sku {sku}".format(name=name, resourcegroup=resourcegroup, subcription=subscription, location=location, sku=sku), shell=True ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: That was my current code and I changed my variables to match.

Comment: And this is my HTML on the form

        <label for="subscription">Subscription Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="subscription" name="subscription"><br>